# Does the unique morphism to the terminal cone over a diagram always preserve right compositions?

Tags: category-theory

Let $\langle f,g \rangle : Y \to A\times B $ denote the unique function given in the universal construction for the product. It is well known that given $h : Z \to Y$ that $\langle f \circ h , g \circ h \rangle = \langle f , g \rangle \circ h$.

My question is, if we have a cone over a general diagram $D$ with tip $Y$ and morphisms $f_i : Y \to D_i$, and we denote the unique morphisms to the terminal cone by $\langle f_1, f_2, \dots, f_n \rangle : Y \to \lim(D)$, does a similar identity always hold? i.e. for $h : Z \to Y$ we have: $$ \langle f_1 \circ h, f_2 \circ h, \dots, f_n \circ h \rangle = \langle f_1, f_2, \dots, f_n \rangle \circ h$$

Or does this only hold for products in general?

Comment: This is just unrolling the definitions. You need to show the RHS satisfies the universal property defining the map on the LHS.